# Removing default listing fields from Wordpress Auction Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been working on removing default field named "Condition" from Wordpress Auction Theme (http://www.premiumpress.com/wordpress-auction-theme/) so I was looking in wordpress editor to find that specific div and delete him,so I  haven't found it in any of that files because it's all written in php.

I 've done the css styling by hidding it in style.css file in wordpress editor.

```
<style>
#form-row-rapper-condition {
display:none;
}
#auctionbidbox tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

I managed to hide that element and it is not showing on desktop. But when I looked it on mobile it was still there.

Can someone help me to remove this field?

Comment: Did you update the stylesheet for mobile as well?

Comment: I haven't. How to do that?

Comment: There's a structural element to stylesheets, and there are alternative sections for different display widths.  I'd really need to see the whole stylesheet in effect to figure out just where it is, but if you look for something in there like `@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px)` or similar that should get you into the right place.

Comment: Thank you for applying. I already tryed that before,I managed to fix this by copying css style to theme's personal additional css editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed error with pasting this style to theme's personal editor:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 0px){
 `#form-row-rapper-condition {
  display:none !important;
  }
  #auctionbidbox tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
  display:none !important;
  }
}
```

Dashboard-Theme Setup-Custom CSS import.